# jQuery fillRect or Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a little rpg game like RPG MO (http://rpg.mo.ee/) with jQuery and I have few questions.

I am making "click to move" movement system and I was thinking is better to use DIVs or fillRect? I mean, if I use fillRect, I do it like this (block is a character):

```
var blockX = 250;
var blockY = 250;
var blockWidth = 25;
var blockHeight = 25;

function drawBlock() {
     ctx.fillRect(blockX, blockY, blockWidth, blockHeight);
}
```

And then I do animate function and call it every 20ms. Otherwise, if I use DIVs, I control them with css. Which way is better to do when I am making that "click to move" movement system?

Other question: How to make tile map? Is it best way to do with array? Can you give me a little example, thanks.

Comment: I recommend turning your tiling question into another post.  As it stands, your post is too broad.  Also, you should consider re-wording so your question isn't asking for an opinion (i.e., "which is better").  That type of question does not fit the convention on stackoverflow.

Comment: However, I do think that your question (if asked the right way) could yield some good answers that others will find useful.

Comment: To clarify, asking "which is more efficient and why" would be better.